# Node.js : Path error loading JSON file using express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, filepath

I have a set of folders and files made this way:

```
viz
|_ app.js // node application
|_ public
        |_ css
                |_ bubblemap.css
        |_ images
        |_ nuts
                |_ nuts0.json
        |_ script
                |_ bubblemap.js
|_ views
        |_ bubblemap.hbs
```

**bubblemap.hbs**:

```
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>Bubblemap</title>
        <script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js' charset='utf-8'></script>
        <link href='/css/bubblemap.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>

    <script> 
        var viewData = {}; 
        viewData.dataHome = JSON.parse('{{json dataHome }}'.replace(/&quot;/g, '"').replace(/&lt;/, ''));
        viewData.dataWork = JSON.parse('{{json dataWork}}'.replace(/&quot;/g, '"').replace(/&lt;/, ''));    
    </script>

    <script src='/script/bubblemap.js' rel='script'/><{{!}}/script>
</html>
```

**bubblemap.js**:

```
(function() {
    var files = ['../nuts/nuts0.json', '../nuts/nuts2.json'];
    var promises = [];

    promises.push(d3.json(files[0]));
    promises.push(d3.json(files[1]));

    Promise.all(promises)
        .then(makeBubblemap)
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log('Error loading files!');
            throw err;
        });

    function makeBubblemap(data) {
        var nuts0 = data[0];
        var nuts2 = data[1];
        var home = viewData.dataHome;
        var work = viewData.dataWork;
    }
)
```

And this is the node app file.

**viz/app.js**:

```
// import...
var app = express();
const webapp_options = {'port': 3000};
initialize();

async function initialize() {
    await postgreSQLlib.connect();

    app.set('views', '' + __dirname + '/views'); 
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 
    app.set('view engine', 'hbs'); 
    app.engine('hbs', hbs.__express); 

    hbs.registerHelper('json', function(context) {
        return JSON.stringify(context);
    });

    app.get('/bubblemap', bubblemap);

    app.listen(webapp_options.port, function() {
        console.log('Ready & listening on http://localhost:' + webapp_options.port + '/');
    });
}

async function bubblemap(req, res) {
    // download data from db
    var dataWork = await postgreSQLlib.getTableHome();
    var dataHome = await postgreSQLlib.getTableWork();

    // create and fill object to pass to view
    var viewData = {}; 
    viewData.dataWork = dataWork;
    viewData.dataHome = dataHome;

    // pass data to view
    res.render('bubblemap', viewData);
}
```

I get this error:

> Error loading files! 
>   Error: 404 Not Found

That is, the nuts0 and nuts2 files are not picked up correctly.
I think it's a path problem but it seems right to me.

I try: `../nuts/nuts0.json`, `./nuts/nuts0.json`, `nuts/nuts0.json` but nothing works.

Comment: Are you deploying your application in the root ( / ) context path? Or with a different context (/app) ? This could explain it.

Comment: @user2037710 Thanks for your help. **viz/app.js** is a file that starts a server that I need for visualizations. To launch the app use `node app.js` in the `/viz` folder.
I added the **viz/app.js** code in the main message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the resource probably couldn't be loaded due to the webapp not serving it...
This can be proved by trying to access to the url of the json file.

### Then it depends how you want to serve the `JSON` :

## Filesystem

#### ·`Serve Static : /public/file.json`

In this example you would have the files in a public accesible folder, and they would be served as static content from the filesystem.

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Make a folder called public and store the jsons inside, they will be accesible under the webapp's root `localhost:3000/nuts0.json`
[Learn more on serving static files in express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

#### ·`Send File : /private/file.json`

In this example you still have a JSON as a file in the filesystem, but not in a web accessible (public) folder (like the example above).
Instead here you are serving it as a resource in a router path (GET Request) and you could even apply pre-serving checks (if request has required cookies,parameters,...)

```
app.get("/jsonFiles/nut0.json",(req,res)=>{
 res.sendFile(__dirname+"/private/nuts0.json")
})
```

### [More on express : sendFile](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile)

## Dynamicly Generated upon GET request

In this example you have no file in your filesystem, but you build it in real-time upon a request (from database, memory, ...)
You can also apply pre-serving checks on this one (does the user have the required permissions,cookie,request parameters, etc..)

```
global.example_counter = 0; //in memory (global) variable
app.get("/jsonFiles/a-virtual-path-for-the-json",(req,res)=>{
 example_request_counter++
 res.json({"total requests":example_request_counter})
})
```

"jsonFiles" doesn't need to exists, that is the path for the webapp's router at the end what is served is what is in the `res.send / res.json`

```
global.inMemoryDB = { //in memory (global) variable
 "nuts0":{"data":"the universe is in fact a multiverse"},
 "nuts1":{"data":"tesla was bright"},
 "nuts2":{"data":"sugar kills..."},
}; 
//router path
app.get("/jsonFiles/:j",(req,res)=>{
 if(inMemoryDB[req.params.j]){res.json(inMemoryDB[req.params.j])}
 else{res.json({"error":"non-existing virtual file requested"}
)}
// http://localhost:3000/jsonFiles/nuts0 will serve you the inMemory json
```

[Learn more on req.params (Express API Doc)](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req)

---

Personally, mainly for production, I would use NGINX as reverse proxy to your node.js apps & serve the static content with it instead.